# direct messaging using spring-social-twitter 1.1.2

Tags: java, twitter, spring-social-twitter

I am working on a legacy application that posts Direct Messages to Twitter Users from our product. The API that was used is **DirectMessageTemplate.sendDirectMessage(String toScreenName, String text)** in spring-social-twitter 1.1.2. The call is now failing with the error message **"Sorry that page does not exist**". My analysis is making me believe that the URL that was constructed by this Spring API is "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/new.json" and it is not working; I believe it should have been https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/events/new.json. I am not sure if my analysis is entirely correct but I see that the second URL is successful when hit from POSTMAN. Can any one please enlighten if this analysis is correct and if yes, is there any other latest version of spring-social-twitter which addresses this ? Also, please suggest if you have any java code snippet that can post OAuth1.0 request to twitter, with pure java ( not using any libraries ). 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There's an [existing issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-twitter/issues/127) on spring-social-twitter that suggests this has not been updated to support the new endpoint. You'd have to work with the maintainers to have them add support for the new API structure.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andy, for the confirmation !